# Php - Jpeg Compression Results a Larger Sized File

Tags: php

I have this image https://ilactarif.com.tr/images/bg1.jpg which i want to compress.

I am using the code below to achieve this task.

```
$filename=/path/to/file;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

$quality = 50;

imagejpeg($img, /path/to/store/compressed/file, $quality);
```

No matter what quality i choose, it always ends with a file that has size of ~31kb. What can i do to solve this ?

Thank in Advance

Comment: Is that a huge unicolored image? If so, what is the point? Or are you just using that for testing? Try with an actual picture. Like, a photograph. See if that makes a difference. (Hint: it will)

Comment: It is just for test purposes. There are gonna be hundreds of images. Unfortunately, your hint was proven wrong :)

Comment: So you tried compressing a photograph (or similar image) with different quality levels and the file size was always the same?

Comment: Yes. No matter the image or quality choosen for compression, file size always comes out larger with the same value

Answer (score 0):

Google outsourced a jpeg compression tool Guetzli. Maybe you could use that to achieve compression.
Once you have Guetzli installed you could simply invoke
`exec("guetzli $filename $path_to_store_compressed_file");`

You can read more about Guetzli here https://github.com/google/guetzli